# Is there a way to get chrome-devtools (--inspect) to automatically detach from a process that has ended?

Tags: node.js, debugging, v8

The process, as it is:

1. start code with --debug --inspect:

   `"debug": "node --max-old-space-size=8192  --debug=5567  --inspect dist/index.js",`
2. Open devtools with url provided, something like:

   `chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@62cd277117e6f8ec53e31b1be58290a6f7ab42ef/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node`
3. Do some debugging.
4. Realize you have a bug, kill process (Ctrl-C) and make code changes.
5. Restart.
6. Start fails: `Unable to open devtools socket: address already in use`
7. Realize that you have to manually refresh the `chrome-devtools` page to get it to realize the process is no longer available.

Node inspector was much better about this. Is there something I'm missing? Some flag that will make the `chrome-devtools` automatically detach from a process that has stopped?

```
$ versions
npm 3.10.3
node v6.7.0
OS Darwin 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0
```

edit: I started using **Node Inspector Manager** (Chrome extension) and found that this whole process went much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have that problem, chrome-devtools shows me a message that the debugging connection was closed when I `Ctrl-C` the node process.

What system are you running on? Maybe that's something that's been fixed in a newer Node or Chrome version? Or maybe you have something in your Node app that prevents proper shutdown of the socket. Can you try with a simple script instead?

jcollum here (user835611 should get the answer credit, since they tipped me off):

I had two listeners for the process termination signals:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  logger.warn('SIGINT received. Shutting down.');
  return process.exit(0);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  logger.warn('SIGTERM received. Shutting down.');
  return process.exit(0);
});
```

Turns out those were blocking chrome's dev tools from seeing the shutdown. I don't know how that would work but that's what I observed. Commenting out `process.exit` made no change. How odd, it seems that having a listener on the `SIGTERM / INT` events blocks Chrome's dev tools from seeing that the process has exited. Never seen a side effect like that from an event listener.

Comment: It wasn't a 6.5.0 problem. But you were right with the simpler code. It works fine with Hello World node sample. Breaks with Hapi.js codebase I'm running. How odd. I'll update if I figure it out.